# Reading from a file deletes the last letter of the last string in the document?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I am writing code which take a .txt doc and stores each word on each line of that .txt file in a list of strings. However my code decides it wants to delete the last letter of the last string for some random reason, can anyone tell me why?

My code:

```
import sys
listofStr = []
print (" ")   
fname = input("Please enter file name: ")
print (" ")

try :
    f = open(fname)

    myLine = f.readline()
    tuplist = []
    while (len(myLine)>0) :
         strings = myLine[:-1]


        listofStr.append(strings)
        myLine = f.readline()



    f.close()

except IOError as e :
     print("Problem opening file (Remember the file extension '.txt')")
     sys.exit()

print(listofStr)
```

when ran:

```
Please enter file name: test.txt

['TEST', 'WAS', 'VERY', 'SUCCESSFU']
```

expected outcome:

```
['TEST','WAS','VERY','SUCCESSFUL']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're slicing the last line which doesn't have the newline character:

```
strings = myLine[:-1]
```

To fix this you can just manually go to your file and append an extra line. Or change said line to `strings = myLine.strip()`. There is no need to slice the string manually since `strip` will handle whitespace and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

The last line doesn't have a linebreak in it, so when you do

```
     strings = myLine[:-1]
```

you strip off the last char in the line, no matter what it is, and you kill off an actual character.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the final newline on your file, so the `strings = myLine[:-1]` removes the final character. If you replace this with `strings = myLine.rstrip()` that will remove any trailing whitespace on the line but won't remove that final character.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
while (len(myLine)>0) :
     strings = myLine[:-1]
     listofStr.append(strings)
     myLine = f.readline()
```

to this:

```
while myLine.strip() :
     strings = myLine.strip()
     listofStr.append(strings)
     myLine = f.readline()
```